# How to use JavaScript console commands in Python + Selenium?

Tags: javascript, python, selenium

I have used JavaScript commands in the console to get a `tbody` element but they don't work when using them in my code.

I have tried using `webdriver.execute_script` to run my code.

```
table_body = browser.execute_script("""
    cd(window.frames[2][1])
    var tbody = document.getElementsByClassName("sortable")[0].children[1]
    return tbody
""")
```

I was expecting this to return a `tbody` element or a HTMLCollection, instead I get an error:

`selenium.common.exceptions.JavascriptException: Message: ReferenceError: cd is not defined`

Comment: What's `cd` here?

Comment: It's should be defined in your JS code.

Comment: If cd is a method then it should be defined in execute_script.

Comment: cd Allows you to change command-line expression evaluation from the default top-level window of the webpage to the window of a frame.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/samples/gg589530(v=vs.85)#UsingCDacrossFrames